# PDF of a Lognormal Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have tried to draw a distribution function with a given mean and standard deviation. However, drawing the distribution function only shows the histograms and not the distribution function and I do not know why it is not drawn:

```
mean = 15.14
stdev = 0.3738
phi = (stdev ** 2 + mean ** 2) ** 0.5
mu = np.log(mean ** 2 / phi)
sigma = (np.log(phi ** 2 / mean ** 2)) ** 0.5
data=np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma , 1000)
mu, sigma, n= lognorm.fit(data) 
plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True, alpha=0.5, color='b')
# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)
p = lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "LogNormal Distribution: Media: {:.2f} y Dev.Est: {:.2f}".format(mean, stdev)
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

The result that I have obtained:

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you remove the line `plt.hist(...)`?

Comment: It looks like there is a black line a the bottom of the plot, this could be it. Where is `lognorm` defined?

Comment: When I delete the histogram I obtain a line with constant values of 0 but I don't understand why. lognorm is imported from scipy.stats.

Comment: So your question is "why does `lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)` return zeros".

Comment: Yes that my question.

Comment: What are the actual values of `mu` and `sigma` that you are passing to `lognorm.pdf`?

Comment: These are the values: mu=2.7170355535799082 sigma =0.024685802777891175

Comment: The distribution that i want to plot is similar to the histogram that I have shown,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the line:

```
mu, sigma, n = lognorm.fit(data)
```

there you are overwriting `mu` and `sigma` values used later.
`lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)` returns zeros because you are evaluating the PDF far away from the mean, where the PDF is actually zero.
In order to properly center the PDF on the mean value, you should replace this line of your code:

```
p = lognorm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
```

with:

```
p = lognorm.pdf(x = x, scale = mean, s = sigma)
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm

mean = 15.14
stdev = 0.3738
phi = (stdev ** 2 + mean ** 2) ** 0.5
mu = np.log(mean ** 2 / phi)
sigma = (np.log(phi ** 2 / mean ** 2)) ** 0.5
data=np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma , 1000)
# mu, sigma, n= lognorm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, bins=30, density=True, alpha=0.5, color='b')
# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)
p = lognorm.pdf(x = x, scale = mean, s = sigma)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
title = "LogNormal Distribution: Media: {:.2f} y Dev.Est: {:.2f}".format(mean, stdev)
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

[image]